# Wsdl stream close with http 400 response

Tags: java, ssl, soap, wsdl, tls1.2

Today my application has been shutting down.
When my Service tries to connect to wsdl url, the connection crashes with http 400 return.

I think the bug appears because the server was up to TLS1.2 but without certitude.

```java
protected Service(java.net.URL wsdlDocumentLocation, QName serviceName) {
        delegate = Provider.provider().createServiceDelegate(wsdlDocumentLocation,
                serviceName,
                this.getClass());
 }
```

> 2019-08-01 08:36:03,271 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR
>   com.illicado.demat.batch.ExternalBatch  - 2 counts of
>   InaccessibleWSDLException.
>
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2
>   counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.
>
> java.io.IOException: Got Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for
>   URL:
>   https://oney.wscartecadeauoney.fr:443/acp-soap/recuperationCarte.wsdl
>   while opening stream from
>   https://oney.wscartecadeauoney.fr:443/acp-soap/recuperationCarte.wsdl
>   java.io.IOException: Got Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for
>   URL:
>   https://oney.wscartecadeauoney.fr:443/acp-soap/recuperationCarte.wsdl?wsdl
>   while opening stream from
>   https://oney.wscartecadeauoney.fr:443/acp-soap/recuperationCarte.wsdl?wsdl

```
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:183)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:155)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:120)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:258)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:221)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:169)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:101)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
at com.illicado.demat.core.util.wsdl.recup.webservice.RecuperationService.<init>(RecuperationService.java:38)
at com.illicado.demat.core.util.wsdl.recup.impl.WSDLRecupCarteUtilities.execute(WSDLRecupCarteUtilities.java:96)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.illicado.demat.batch.ExternalBatch.recuperationCarte(ExternalBatch.java:200)
at com.illicado.demat.batch.ExternalBatch.doTheJob(ExternalBatch.java:85)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor91.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```